# mpl_to_plotly x-tick labels missing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

Using mpl_to_plotly to convert a seaborn plot, the x-tick labels disappear. How can we make them appear?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly
import seaborn as sns
​
iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('iris').data
sns.barplot(x='Species', y='Sepal.Length', data=iris)
mpl_fig = plt.gcf()
plotly_fig = mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
plotly.offline.iplot(plotly_fig)
```

[image]

See: Species carry labels 0, 1, 2 instead of setosa, versicolor, virginica.

Comment: The cause of the label not being converted is unknown, but the [community](https://community.plotly.com/t/showing-matplotlib-figures-with-dash-mpl-to-plotly/15710/3) has commented that it is deprecated in the answer to the following question. This question and your phenomenon are not necessarily the same. If you need labels, add them. `plotly_fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2], ticktext=['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'])`